# Call a method from another class without initialization in java

Tags: java, function, class, data-structures, methods

I’m a bit confused by the code below. From my understanding, `private ListElement<E> head`is just the same thing as saying `int head`. If this is true, then one cannot call a method from an outside class without initializing it, so `head.setPrev()` won’t work before you say `ListElment<E> head = new ListElment<>()`. which contradicts the code below. I must have misunderstood something about java. Cloud someone points it out? Thanks in advance

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

private ListElement<E> head;
private ListElement<E> tail;



public DoublyLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
}

public void addToHead(E value) {
    ListElement<E> e = new ListElement<>(value);

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        e.setNext(head);
        head.setPrev(e);
    } else { // empty
        tail = e;
    }

    head = e;
}
```

Comment: `ListElement<E>` is _not_ the same as `int`, as `ListElement` holds the value stored in the list (and could be anything, not just an `int`).

Comment: So If I define `ListElement<E>  x`, then I can use `x.method()` to call all the methods in ListElement<E> without initializing x?

Comment: That would only be true if you gave `x` a value. Without initialization, `ListElement<E> x;` is `null`, which would cause a `NullPointerException` if you called any methods on it. What I was saying before is that one is an object, the other is a primitive (which is initialized to `0` and has _no methods_), and both are completely different things.

Comment: It’s much clear to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You omitted the code for `isEmpty()`.

Assuming a reasonable implementation, then if `isEmpty()` returns `false`, then it is *guaranteed* that `head` is not null, because there has to be at least one element in the list if it's not empty.

`head` is a *reference* to a `ListElement` object.  It starts out initialized to `null`.  On the very first call to `addToHead()` the call to `isEmpty()` returns `true`, so the `else` branch of the if-then-else executes.  The end result is that after that first call, both `head` and `tail` now refer to the element just created.

The "then" branch executes only if the list is not empty, in which case, by definition, `head` cannot be null.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn’t copy all the code, cause my point here is `head.setPrev()`, "head" seems to be defined as a variable here from `private ListElement<E> head)`, but  `head.setPrev(e)` obviously is treating "head" as an object

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, so we can define a reference in data structures by the way like `Classname refname`?

Comment: and use `refname.method()` to call methods in "Classname"  directly ?

Comment: Yes.  All object variables in Java are references.  The statement `SomeClass x;` declares only a reference to an instance of `SomeClass`. The only way an instance ever gets created is with `new`, as in `x = new SomeClass();`  This is all very basic Java... I suggest you look at Oracle's online tutorials.

Comment: got it, Thank you